# Unable to find NaN value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have NaN values in my Data Frame....
when I run command "`Data[Data['column_name'].isnull().any(axis=1)]`"
can't find any NaN value. Please help me out

Comment: `Data['column_name'].isna().any()`

Comment: Sure, all I need is your ip, username, and password. I can ssh into your computer and take a look. Otherwise, you could make things simpler by providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It returns all the Nan or None values for that column along axis=1.

```
Data[Data['ColumnName'].isnull()]
```